# Perforce: How to create a new stream at a specific changelist

Tags: branch, perforce

I have a streamed depot with a mainline and development branches.  We're currently at CL #10.
I want to create a new branch something like //project/side_branch but populated with files from CL #5.  Effectively a snapshot of the mainline branch at an older changelist.

I can't figure out how to do this, when I create a new stream it automatically populates it with the latest version from mainline.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new stream:

```
p4 stream -t development -P //project/main //project/side_branch
```

and populate it from the desired changelist:

```
p4 populate -S //project/side_branch -r @5
```

Comment: Hmm, seemed promising but I get `Can't populate target path when files already exist.`

Comment: If there are already files in there, then you're not creating a new stream.

Comment: If you want to just overwrite the contents of an existing stream, use `p4 copy`, e.g. `p4 copy --from main @5`.

Comment: Ok, you were right, I had deleted the earlier stream I'd created incorrectly.  But of course P4 didn't actually delete it, merely removed it from the stream graph.  So when I recreated it there were all the old files still there.  I can't obliterate so I had to create a new stream and then your commands worked fine on it.  Thanks for the speedy assistance!